# USING IF with UPDATE MYSQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sql-update

Im trying to do an update with a IF function

```
IF(SELECT 'FUNCION' FROM tickets 
  WHERE (FUNCION = COR) AND (tickets.CLIENTE=clientes.CLIENTE)) 
THEN UPDATE `clientes` SET `ESTADO` = 'I';
```

I tried this but it seems I have a syntax error.

How can I get this to work?

EDIT: I want to update 'ESTADO' to 'I' if 'FUNCION', from another table, is 'COR' and the fields 'CLIENTE' match each other.

Comment: *"it seems I have a syntax error."* - So, what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a join operation in an UPDATE statement.

It's not clear to me what `COR` is a reference to, so I'm going to assume it's supposed to be a string literal, not a reference to a column name.

Here's an example:

```
UPDATE clientes c
  JOIN tickets t
    ON t.cliente = c.cliente
   AND t.funcion = 'COR'
   SET c.estado = 'I'
```

That says, find all rows in `clientes` that have a "matching" row in `tickets`, and set the `estado` column to `'I'` on those rows.

---

Think about it this way... write a SELECT query first to identify the rows you want to update, and filter out the ones you don't.

```
SELECT c.*             -- please don't use * in code in applications! 
     , t.funcion
  FROM clientes c
  JOIN tickets t
    ON t.cliente = c.cliente
   AND t.funcion = 'COR'
```

*--or--*

```
SELECT c.*
  FROM clientes c
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM tickets t
                 WHERE t.cliente = c.cliente
                   AND t.funcion = 'COR'
               )
```

Once you have a `SELECT` statement working (that retrieves ONLY the rows you want to update), you can convert that into an `UPDATE`, by replacing `SELECT ... FROM` with the keyword `UPDATE`, and add a `SET` clause before the `WHERE` clause.

There's also some "tricks" we can play in the expression in the `SET`, to do some conditional assignment. To leave the column unchanged, assign the current value back to the column.

For example, to replace only NULL values of `estado`

```
  SET c.estado = IF(c.estado IS NULL,'I',c.estado)
```

If the boolean expression (first argument in the IF() function) evaluates to TRUE, then return the result of the evaluation of the second argument (in this example `'I'`), otherwise, return the current value of the `estado` column.

Comment: That's what I was looking to do. thank you. And sorry I'm pretty new.

Comment: Sorry if I ask you again, now I'm trying to add an ORDER BY. how can I added? I tried but its says that is incorrect to use UPDATE and ORDER BY functions.

Comment: An `ORDER BY` clause cannot be used in a multi-table update statement, only a single table update. I apologize if I led you to believe that could. (It's not clear me *why* you'd need to update the rows in a particular sequence, but...) you can start with the SELECT statement (above) that has the EXISTS  clause. That statement only references a single table in the outer query, so you should be able to convert that one to an UPDATE with an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Is because on the FUNCION column there's COR or REI values and somes t.CLIENTE has more than one COR record, so I just need that if the last record for t.CLIENTE is COR changes c.ESTADO to 'I'.

Comment: How do you determine which row in `t` is the "last" row for a given value of `CLIENTE`? It's likely that you identify that without using an `ORDER BY`. You're looking for the "last" row in `t`. In an UPDATE statement, the ORDER BY would operate only on the single table in the outer query (rows in `c`) so an order by isn't going to help you there.

Comment: may I LAST(FUNCION) for t.CLIENTE for it? I tried but it doesn´t goes.

Comment: MySQL does not support the `LAST()` aggregate function; that's not available. And a comparison of values of `FUNCION` values on the rows is likely not going to get you the desired result. What column values would you compare to determine if a row is before or after another row... is there a date, datetime, timestamp, or sequence number column?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you write a conditional update. Use a `where` clause:

```
UPDATE clientes
SET estado='I'
WHERE (funcion = cor) AND (tickets.client=clients.cliente)
```

This won't work, since you're referring to fields/tables that aren't joined into the query.

Comment: In this case 'funcion' is from another table. I'm trying to get an update to estado = 'I' if funcion from another table is COR